# Old story about a creature laying pyramid shaped eggs on Mars

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens, mars, novella

I remember a very old short story/novella about a man on Mars who finds a creature who lays pyramid shaped eggs, the eggs hatch and a new creature lays an egg and so on. Think the man is a stranded astronaut but can really remember what the purpose of being on Mars or anything else the creature does. Had 50's sort of feel to it but not sure.

Comment: 30s, not 50s. The man is a member of an exploring party on Mars, not stranded. You can read the story at [Project Gutenberg](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/23731).

Comment: Not really eggs either, but the creature's waste product.

Comment: We don't close story id questions as duplicate unless both are accepted.

Comment: Thanks to all!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is Stanley G Weinbaum's "[A Martian Odyssey](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41168)".

> There was a line of little pyramids - tiny ones, not more than six
> inches high, stretching across Xanthus as far as I could see.

Also the answer to this old question: [Story about a man and an alien exploring an alien world](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/97211/story-about-a-man-and-an-alien-exploring-an-alien-world/97215#97215)